# Can I get integer values for a 2D array instead of characters?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, 2d

I was trying to create the simpliest matrix - 2d array and I have trouble with my code, it is kind of working, but not correctly.
Code:

```
int result = 0;
    int[][] matrix = new int[2][2];
    for(int rows = 0; rows < matrix.length; rows++)
        for(int cols = 0; cols < matrix[rows].length; cols++)
           matrix[rows][cols] = (rows + cols); 
            System.out.println("matrix is: "+matrix);

    result = matrix[0][0]*matrix[1][1]-matrix[0][1]*matrix[1][0];
    System.out.println("Result is: "+result);
```

Output:
matrix is: [[I@1db9742

Result is: -1

I had this one:

```
int result = 0;
    char[][] matrix= new char[2][2];
    for(int rows = 0; rows < 2; rows++)
        for(int cols = 0; cols < 2; cols++)
           matrix[rows][cols] = (char)('1' + rows * 2 + cols);
    for(int rows = 0; rows < 2; rows++)
        for(int cols = 0; cols < 2; cols++)
            System.out.println("matrix is: "+matrix[rows][cols]);
    result = matrix[0][0]*matrix[1][1]-matrix[0][1]*matrix[1][0];
    System.out.println("Result is: "+result);
```

Output:
matrix is: 1

matrix is: 2

matrix is: 3

matrix is: 4

Result is: -2

But I do not want char, I want integer (because what if work with big matrix calculations later) and I do not understand tis part:

```
('1' + rows * 2 + cols)
```

because I copied it from some other code. How to get the first one to work like second and what is that part in brackets (why writen like that)? Thanks in advance!

I got nice stuff with 1 2 3 4 that is what I wanted, but I also need explanation for what that "('1' + rows * 2 + cols)" means. I want to get 1 2 3 4 for matrix 2D array, and then 1*4-2*3 for result. Maybe '1' is to start from 1, not from 0 in loop and write from 1 in array. I found it in some other code, not my solution, first one is mine and not working properly. I added:

```
for(int cols = 0; cols < matrix[rows].length; cols++)
```

as you suggested.

*I rewrote it to english. 
Sorry for language confusion.
I don’t understand why I get characters instead of 2D array when printing matrix after loop, before calculating.

Comment: What are you trying to do here: (char)('1' + redovi * 2 + kolone)? should the '1' be 1. You can't get one char from this statement as is.

Comment: This will not work: System.out.println("Rezultat je: "+rezultat);

Comment: For the matrix. For the loop use : 
`for(int redovi = 0; redovi < matrica.length; redovi++)
        for(int kolone = 0; kolone < matrica[redovi].length; kolone++)`

Comment: You should switch to english names and console output, as it's the lingua franca of coding. While it's not hard to get a hint of what this algorithm does by simply reading the implementation, using english will help a lot when you're asking questions; especially when the code gets more complex.

Answer (score 0):

I think the result is correct.
This is your matrix :

| 0 1 |

| 1 2 |

And this is what you do : 0 * 2 - 1 * 1 
and the good answer is = -1.

The code for what you want is :

```
int i = 1;
for(int redovi = 0; redovi < matrica.length; redovi++)
    for(int kolone = 0; kolone < matrica.length; kolone++)
       matrica[redovi][kolone] = i; 
       ++i;
```

So we will get a matrix like this one :

|1 2|

|3 4|

And so the good answer for what you want. If I well understood.

Answer (score 0):

You should look closer on what you write into matrix. The first looks like:

```
0 1
1 2
```

and second:

```
'1' '2'
'3' '4'
```

So both determinants are calculated almost as you expect. You can change one line in the first code to this:

```
matrix[rows][cols] = (1 + rows*matrix[rows].length + cols);
```

So that your matrix is 1234.

By the way, using char[][] worked because any char can be represented as a number that is an index in character map.

> I also need explanation for what that "('1' + rows * 2 + cols)" means

Character '1' is 49th in character map, '2' is 50th and so on. Try to compile this, for example:

```
System.out.println((int)'1');
```

So "('1' + rows * 2 + cols)" generates a matrix that can be represented as int[][]:

```
49 50
51 52
```